# 500 error with Adwords API on v2011109 sandbox

Tags: perl, api, soap, wsdl, google-ads-api

I need to create a sandbox account: http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/sandbox.html

Unfortunately, I'm getting a 500 error when issuing the GET against the WSDL location they supplied, (No such operation:  (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /v201109/CampaignService))

That link states:

> To create a sandbox account, send a get request to the sandbox
>   version of CampaignService, using the WSDL location and sandbox
>   headers as described below. This initial call to the sandbox creates
>   an MCC sandbox account, along with five client accounts, for the email
>   address you specified. Your sandbox account and its client accounts
>   start out empty."

I created my authToken with:

```
my $token = Google::Ads::Common::AuthToken::get_token({
    email    => EMAIL,
    password => PASSWORD,
    service  => "adwords"
});
```

However, issuing a GET request to the specified WSDL location results
in a 500 error with the following content:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>No such operation:  (HTTP GET PATH_INFO: /v201109/CampaignService)</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm using the following code:

```
use HTTP::Request;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $wsdl_location =
  'https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109/CampaignService';
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $wsdl_location );
$req->header(
    ":authToken"        => $auth_token,
    ":developerToken"   => EMAIL . '++USD',
    ":userAgent"        => 'weborama',
);

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$ua->add_handler("request_send",  sub { shift->dump; return });
$ua->add_handler("response_done", sub { shift->dump; return });

my $res = $ua->request($req);

if ( $res->is_success ) {
    print $res->content;
}
else {
    print $res->status_line, "\n";
}
```

My request headers:

```
GET https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109/CampaignService
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.02
authToken: *********
developerToken: EMAIL++USD
userAgent: weborama
```

Has anyone made this work with Perl and v201109? Am I missing something obvious? (I'm getting no response from the Google Adwords API forum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want https://adwords-sandbox.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109/CampaignService?wsdl

Comment: That's not the URL they list in their sandbox description. I did try it, however, and it is merely returning a description of the WSDL service and doesn't appear to actually do anything. That being said, I don't know much about WSDL and Google's documentation is sorely lacking here.

Comment: Grab a java-based tool called soapui. It'll take you an hour or less to get to grips with the basics. It can import a wsdl file and generate a set of tests for you. That'll show whether the documentation or code is at fault.

Comment: The problem is that you are reading HTTP while Google is speaking SOAP.  When they say, "send a [get](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/CampaignService.html#get) request to the sandbox version of CampaignService", they mean "make a get method call to the CampaignService SOAP web service."  Also, by request headers, they mean SOAP request headers.  You should take a look at either [Google's Perl API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-perl/) or [Google::Adwords](http://search.cpan.org/~rohan/Google-Adwords-v1.14/) although the later is a bit old.

Comment: @Steve: thank you very much. Looks like that's the issue I have here.